# Need to get Emergency contact list of particular location

Tags: android, google-places-api

Can we can get nearby places information by [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/).

For eg. can we get names of nearby hotel using google places api with the use of LatLong.

Is this possible way to get hotel contact information too? 
or any directory available to get city  nearby located all contact information.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question?

Comment: I want details for particular city's nearby hotels, hospitals, banks, police stations, railway stations contact number.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. 
You have all the information needed on the link you provided, but ill make it clearer for you.

I think that you want to search places based on your location. If so then look here [Autocomplete parameters](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete?hl=en#get_place_predictions_programmatically). There you see a latLngBounds so you can search places close to your location. 
If you want hotels just pass hotels or hotel in the query parameter as you would do it in google maps itself.
After that you would get the information you want and then use [Places ID and Details](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/place-details?hl=en) to get information such as telephone number and all the information google have for that place.

Just read all the documents there and you will figured out how to do everything without problem.

Comment: Thanks for help, but how can I get compete list in one, not by particular search using Autocomplete search? or Is there any way if i tap on map's marker position to getPhoneNumber().

Comment: You need to be clearer of what you want. What do you mean by compete(complete?) list and by particular search. Try to be more clear and edit your question so we can help you more

Comment: For eg. By this call we are getting details except phone number https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?location=<LAT>,<LONG>&radius=10000&query=hotel&key=<KEY> , So how can I get Phone number too.

Comment: Seems like I cant see the link because I dont have a Google Key. Please update your question with the response from the link. Copy the code and paste it on your question so I can help you